# How to create READ ONLY user in redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need to create READ-ONLY user account in redshift cluster db. Once user account created, that user should not be able create any object in PUBLIC.but they can SELECT any object. since CREATE & USAGE privileges are granted to all users by default, pls guide me how to restrict object creation in PUBlic SCHEMA ?

version:

```
PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.735
```

THANK YOU

hi,

I noted your reply. yes it works. But i have a clarification.

If you did below and create any user further in database( existing user also ) , then they wil not be able to create objects in PUBLIC schema.

```
postgres=# REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE
```

so, if i reset back ( i.e. below ), then it applicables to all users and all the users are able to create objects in DB.

```
postgres=# grant create on schema public to public;
GRANT
```

my intention is, I need to restrict object creation ( CREATE priv ) on certain users. not for all db users. For e.g. i need to create 2 users. first one is READ-ONLY. 2nd one is READ-WRITE.  i should be able to revoke the CREATE priv from only that . NOT FROM ALL.

can you guide me if I am wrong.

thank you again

Comment: You can create a group of users and grant only SELECT and USAGE privileges, using `CREATE GROUP` command, but you will need to execute the `REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;` command either way...

Answer (score 3):

As a default, every user can access and create tables on "public" schema because "PUBLIC"(all users) have the all privileges on "public" schema. You can revoke CREATE privilege on "PUBLIC" from users with the following command.

```sql
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

- "public":  Schema name
- "PUBLIC": Identifier of "all users"

After running the above command, you need to run GRANT command which allows users to access "PUBLIC" schema.

```sql
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO {user-name};
```

This doc explains about it.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-schemas.html

Comment: Hi Masashi, Thanks for your previous mail. yes, I am able to revoke CREATE ON public schema from PUBLIC(all users). But I need to specifically REVOKE from one user account, not from all users(PUBLIC). Please guide me on this.